# jsStringFormat() and apostrophe with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion, datatables

So I am having an interesting problem with `jsStringFormat()` when trying to escape special characters for JSON. I am using the jQuery datatables plugin and doing an AJAX call to Coldfusion.

What appears to be happening is that jsStringFormat() is escaping the apostrophe character and putting `\'` in my JSON. According to JSON spec, the single apostrophe doesn't need escaping, thus it breaks.

Here is a sample of my JSON return

```
{
    "sEcho": 2,
    "iTotalRecords": 659,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 201,
    "aaData": [

        ["516", "", "54d 7h 12m", "02- Revenue", "", "Assist in validating error in JCA provided Discount Commission report", "Received", "Work Request", "Jan 1, 2012"],
        ["616", "", "16d 7h 12m", "02- Revenue", "", "Order/Install new POS Terminal at Katie\'s Workstation", "In Progress", "Work Request", "Oct 31, 2011"],
        ["617", "", "15d 7h 12m", "02- Revenue", "", "Replace #6081 POS Printer at Kim\'s Desk", "Received", "Work Request", "Oct 31, 2011"]
    ]
}
```

You can clearly see the `\'` inserted in the descriptions.

I really need to find a way to prevent `jsStringFormat()` from escaping the apostrophe.

---

### UPDATE

So far, have this code for attempting to populate the aaData array. Right now I am getting nothing but commas so I know its looping properly, but not populating the data in the right places.

All of this is based off of datatables coldfusion datasource code http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/coldfusion

```
<cfcontent reset="Yes" />

<cfset aaData = [] />
<cfset datasetRecords = [] />
<cfloop query="qFiltered" startrow="#val(url.iDisplayStart+1)#" endrow="#val(url.iDisplayLength)#">
<cfif currentRow gt (url.iDisplayStart+1)>,</cfif>
        <cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn">
            <cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)>,</cfif>
                <cfif thisColumn is "version">
                    <cfif version eq 0>"-"
                    <cfelse><cfset datasetData["#version#"] />
                    </cfif>
                <cfelse><cfset datasetData[""] = qFiltered[thisColumn][qFiltered.currentRow] />
                </cfif>
                <cfset ArrayAppend(datasetRecords, datasetData ) />
        </cfloop>
<cfset ArrayAppend(datasetRecords, aaData ) />
</cfloop>

<cfset record = {} />
<cfset record["sEcho"] = val(url.sEcho) />
<cfset record["iTotalRecords"] = qCount.total />
<cfset record["iTotalDisplayRecords"] = qFiltered.recordCount />
<cfset record["aaData"] = aaData />

<cfoutput><cfdump var="#record#"></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(record)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: phihag, as John says below: _JSStringFormat is designed for escaping data for inclusion in JavaScript, not JSON._ Also, in the next release Adobe are using the OWASP/ESAPI library, and providing more explicit `encodeForJavaScript` and `encodeForJson` functions.

Comment: @JasonDean Sorry, you're right, that comment was misplaced and trolling. Deleted it.

Comment: @phihag Very big of you. I deleted mine as well. Thx

Comment: I'm assuming that your other question is basically the same as your update here (though obviously you've updated your code a little bit there). You might want to remove it from here, since it's really a different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSStringFormat` is designed for escaping data for inclusion in *JavaScript*, not JSON. In JavaScript, a single quote is a character that needs to be escaped.

On the other hand, [`SerializeJSON`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/functions_s_03.html) is actually meant to output JSON, and complies with the JSON spec.

Comment: Thanks John. With SerializeJSON, will I still be able to input the special prefixes and variables for datatables

`"sEcho": 2,
    "iTotalRecords": 659,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 201,
    "aaData":`

Comment: You can create a structure for the output you want and just throw that at `SerializeJSON` and it will handle converting it and all the values contained within for you. (Use the array notation when creating the structure to make sure CF doesn't convert your key names to uppercase).

Comment: Thanks again John. I will dive into the documentation. Any code examples would be helpful as well.

Comment: There's really nothing to it - here's an example:

`<cfset Data = Struct() /> <cfset Data['MixedCaseName'] = "value" /> ... <cfdump var=#serializeJson(Data)# />`

Comment: Actually, JSStringFormat() is for encoding data in JSON too. Just NOT the whole JSON object. If you need to escape data in a single JSON value you would use JSONFormat(). For example, {mykey: '#JSStringFormat(variabletoBeEncoded)#'}

Comment: @JasonDean This question demonstrates the reason why you *don't* want to use `JSStringFormat` even for escaping individual values: it outputs invalid JSON for some inputs.

Comment: Ah, I see, my mistake. +1 for serializeJSON()

Comment: I'm getting closer. I have the struct created and am up to the point of populating aaData, just having some problems with syntaxing the loop to populate the array.
Posted code above

Answer (score 5):

i ran into the same issue with datatables.  what i did to fix it was create the jsstringformat string and then do a replace on the returned string to remove all instances of \' with '.

```
<cfset thisColumnString = jsStringFormat(trim((qFiltered[thisColumn][qFiltered.currentRow])))>
<cfset thisColumnString = replacenocase(thisColumnString,"\'","'","all")>
"#thisColumnString#"
```