# Coldfusion JSON Breaking with DataTables

Tags: regex, json, coldfusion, datatables

Working on one of the tasks i am using `jsstringformat` function to handle json data if some special characters are used, but that does not seems to handle all issues.

My JSON still breaks.

I am using like this :

```
"<a href='edit.cfm?id=#jsStringFormat(qFiltered.randomnumber)#' style='color:##066D99'>#trim(jsStringFormat(qFiltered[thisColumn][qFiltered.currentRow]))#</a>"
```

I am lost here what else i can use as any part of `regex` or `rereplace` that it should not break

Thanks

Comment: *does not handle all issues*, when does it break? Further, what does the contents of randomnumber look like? Give us some samples.

Comment: random number looks like this: a createuuid kind of: `f1cb5eb1-d4be-d9b1-03a954e136ae496b`

Comment: Try wrapping the whole tag, like `#JSStringFormat("<a...>...</a>")#`. You should be able to remove the JSStringFormat from where you have it.

Comment: What does this have to do with DataTables?  Also, since randomNumber is basically a string, you probably don't need a function.  If you did, then urlencodedformat might be more appropriate.

Comment: yeah but the jsstringformat was used for the data inside the a tags too. trying to see if some regex can help in respect to the jsstringformat also

Comment: You may be over-engineering this.

Comment: Have you tried using `serializeJSON` instead? That would escape any special characters as well.

Comment: JSStringFormat is not designed to handle JSON data. As suggested by David Faber you should use serializeJSON (and DeserializeJSON). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7668518/2482184 .

Answer (score 0):

You're doing multiple things here.

- You're putting the string into a URL: use `UrlEncodedFormat`.
- You're also putting it in an HTML tag: use `HtmlEditFormat`.
- The whole thing is going into a JavaScript variable, so I would use JSStringFormat to wrap the whole thing.

Try building your string before assigning it.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="htmlLink"><cfoutput>
  <a href="edit.cfm?id=#UrlEncodedFormat(qFiltered.randomnumber)#" style="color: ##066D99">#HtmlEditFormat(Trim(qFiltered[thisColumn][qFiltered.currentRow]))#</a>
</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>
myJsVar = "#JsStringFormat(Trim(htmlLink))#";
```